# Form W-8BEN at multiple stock brokers

Tags: united-states, taxes, brokerage, form-w-8-ben

I am a non-resident alien. I have an existing US stock brokerage account. When I opened that account, I had to fill in and submit a W-8BEN form. Now, I am going to open a second US stock brokerage account at a different brokerage firm. I will have to fill in a W-8BEN form again.

1. Do I have to inform my first broker that I am going to fill and submit a second W-8BEN form?
2. Do I have to inform my second broker that I had filled in and submitted a W-8BEN form in the past?
3. Suppose I will be opening 10 brokerage accounts at 10 different brokerage firms. Can I send all of them the same copy of a filled W-8BEN form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No
2. No
3. Yes the copies are supposed to be identical (same address, same residence, same treaty). You are supposed to inform ALL broker if your personal particulars have changed.